Saving printed data to file in python
I want to calculate numbers with trys in the Collatz Conjecture in python. I have the collatz conjecture code down, but I want to save the printed result to a .txt file. Does anyone have any tips on how to make this work?
I have played around with my dictionary and pandas, but it doesn't really do what I want to do. I have tried to write the answers to a file, but it all shows up on one line and it is not useful.

If you already have a script that's printing the results, just redirect its output to the file: python collatz.py > collatz.txt

You can also use the file=filestream option to the print() function to have it write to an open file.

If you want more concrete suggestions, you need to post your attempt. Then we can tell you what you did wrong and show how to fix it.

Thanks for the help.

This question is similar to: Correct way to write line to file?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To save the printed results to a file, you can modify your code wherever you have the print statement for the results of your calculation. Below the print statement, add the following code to write the output to a file:
with open("results.txt", "a") as file:  # Open the file in append mode
    file.write(f"{your_result}\n")  # Replace 'your_result' with the variable being printed


Thank you! That works great.
